# Can we inject a service inside of a wcf message inspector?

Tags: .net, wcf, autofac, idispatchmessageinspector

I have a wcf application where I've a message inspector (IDispatchMessageInspector). Now I want to inject a service into it but can't figure out how to do that or if it's possible or not.

I've a mvc project in the same solution and I can do property injection in mvc action filters but not sure how to do same with wcf message inspectors.

Here is my message inspector:

```
    public class MessageValidator : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public IFeatureService FeatureService { get; set; }
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
          ///
        }
   }
```

And I've tried registering my message validator in the autofac bootstrapper like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MessagaeValidator>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired();
```

The registration for IFeatureService is already done and working fine in other wcf services but can't make it work inside of a message inspector.
How can I do this?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) it shouldn't be possible. service message inspectors implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface: Defines the methods that enable custom inspection or modification of inbound and outbound application messages in service applications.

Comment: [Message Inspectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors)